# ReferenceError: Property '_globalSetter' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native

I really can't place my hands on more clues to where this error is coming from or even how to reproduce it. All I can say is that I was trying to run my react native project and got that error. Anyone who has explanations and possible solution is welcome.
I tried running the project with :

```
npm run android
```

Further error messages :

```
 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), js engine: hermes
```

Comment: I was about to post the same question , this occurred after I have installed reanimated which requires enabling Hermes

Comment: were you able to figure out what the problem is? @سعيد

Comment: I think something related to babel plugins , in Reanimated they mentioned that I should add a certain plugin to babel config and I forgot about that

Comment: @سعيد what is the plugin you missed to add? I have this same problem

Comment: @KimiRaikkonen9790 this one react-native-reanimated/plugin it should be listed last too  please refer to documentation : 
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation